# C++: undefined reference to function, parameters appear changed

Tags: c++

I'm confused with this error message. New to C++, and trying to troubleshoot a build.

Why is the error saying char const* and long? I don't see anywhere these being used. (it's supposed to be const char* and int32). The parameters look changed in the error.

error says

```
undefined reference to `JobContainer::UpdateStatus(char const*, long)'
```

but prototype is

```
void UpdateStatus(const char* status, int32 perc_complete=-1);
```

definition is:

```
void JobContainer::UpdateStatus(const char* status, int32 perc_complete/*=-1*/)
```

call is:

```
static const char* status_ok = "OK";
JOB->UpdateStatus(status_ok, (int32) 0);
```

Oh, and how do I fix this?

Comment: `int32` is not a built-in C++ type. I'm guessing it's typedefed somewhere to be long. But I still can't explain the error.

Comment: `const char*` and `char const*` are the same "pointer to const char" `char * const` is different "const pointer to char"

Comment: What exactly do you think is the difference between `const char*` and `char const*`?  (But then, `char* const` actually *is* different)

Comment: New to c++. Can I assume `const char` and `char const` are the same too?

Answer (score 2):

Your function is *declared*, and it is *defined* in a cpp file (say foo.h and foo.cpp).  The compiler will define a symbol to identify your function, and put the function code in an object file (foo.o).

The function is *referred to* from another module (main.cpp).  The compiler, through the `#include`d declaration, will see that your `main` needs a reference to the function - it will leave an unresolved symbol that needs to be resolved for your code to be able to execute.

This unresolved symbol needs to be resolved by the linker; you will have to tell the linker it needs to lookup unresolved symbols in a bunch of object files (main.o and foo.o).

Possibly, you didn't tell the linker to use the object file containing your function body.

Answer (score 1):

That's because there are *real* types and aliases, e.g.

```
typedef long int32;
```

The alias does not show up in the real signature, which will always contain the real types that are used.

The error you are seeing is unrelated to that. It is most probably a linker error because you are not linking against the file which contains the definition of the method. How to fix it? That depends, which compiler/build-system are you using? Can you show the commands you use to build your application?

Comment: Not sure why it's not linking. I have the relevant /lib directory in my LD_LIBRARY_CONFIG.